# Locale.getDefault() returns en always

Tags: java, linux, unix, locale

Servers on unix machine are always using en as default locale.
Following is locale output

```
 LANG=en_US
 LC_CTYPE="C"
 LC_NUMERIC="C"
 LC_TIME="C"
 LC_COLLATE="C"
 LC_MONETARY="C"
 LC_MESSAGES="C"
 LC_ALL=C
```

I just don't understand if LANG is set correctly then why servers starts with en locale.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In Linux/Unix/Mac, the settings `LC_ALL` and `LANG` can control the default locale for Java programs. In Windows, the locales are set from the Control Panel, under Regional and Language Options.

When the JVM starts in a *nix environment, it will do this:

- Scan the environment for `LC_ALL`
- If `LC_ALL` doesn't exist, scan the environment for `LANG`
- If the JVM setting `user.language` is set, use that in place of the environment variables.
- If nothing is set, default to `en_US` (I believe this is the final failure case)

In your environment, you have `LC_ALL` set to `C`, which is just the C locale. It's basically a traditional fallback to the days when locales weren't used.

You can change `LC_ALL` in your case, and restart your JVM, and you should get a new value for `java.util.Locale.getDefault()`.

Example:

```
import java.util.Locale;

public class LocaleTest {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
   }
}
```

Here's running:

```
> LC_ALL=en_UK java LocaleTest
en_UK

> LC_ALL=ja_JP java LocaleTest
ja_JP
```

Also note that if you're running Java 1.7.0-b147, there is a bug with the JRE not recognizing environment settings for locale, and will always use the default system locale.

Bug report here: https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug?bug_id=7073906

Comment: Thanks birryree. But getDefault method returns Locale based on user.language properties. If these properties are not passed explicitly while running servers like this -Duser.language=en_GB then how these values gets set? Are these properties get sets when user logs into system or jvm sets these properties based on environment.

Comment: @Delta - as I mentioned, it will look at your local environment and use `LC_ALL` or `LANG` variables for the locale when the JVM starts up. If nothing is set, it will default to some hard coded value (`en_US`).

Comment: Thanks birreyree. I'm going to make this change and see if it works correctly.I will keep you posted. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. By setting LC_ALL problem is fixed.