# output of TimeZone.getDefault() method

Tags: java, datetime, locale

When I run the below line,

```
    System.out.println(java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());
```

I got the following output.

```
  sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Calcutta",
  offset=19800000,
  dstSavings=0,
  useDaylight=false,
  transitions=6,
  lastRule=null]
```

and

`System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());` gives

```
`en_US`
```

My doubt is

How could the `Locale` be `en_US`, When My `Zone id` is `Asia/Calcutta`?

in the first output, I haven't understood what are `offset, dstSavings, useDaylight, transitions and rules ?`

Could anybody help in understanding these.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Locale` has nothing to do with `TimeZone`, you can setup your computer in French in Australia if you want... you won't need France TimeZone for that.

To know more about TimeZone, you should read theses :

- [TimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimeZone.html)
- [What is a TimeZone](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/time-zones.html)
- The class that actualy give you the `toString()` : [ZoneInfo](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/util/calendar/ZoneInfo.java)

**useDaylightTime**

```
public abstract boolean useDaylightTime()
```

> Queries if this time zone uses daylight savings time.

What is [Daylight Saving Time](http://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/).

**getDSTSavings**

```
public int getDSTSavings()
```

> Returns the amount of time to be added to local standard time to get local wall clock time.

So this is the difference between the UTC + TimeZone + (DSTSavings - 0 or 1 hour). If you are currently in DST savings mode, will return 1 hour.

**rules**

Rules mean the date when the DST is active and date when it is no more. More info [SimpleTimeZone](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/SimpleTimeZone.html).

**transitions**

> This array describes transitions of GMT offsets of this time zone, including both raw offset changes and daylight saving time changes. A long integer consists of four bit fields.
>
> The most significant 52-bit field represents transition time in
>   milliseconds from Gregorian January 1 1970, 00:00:00 GMT.
>       The next 4-bit field is reserved and must be 0.
>       The next 4-bit field is an index value to offsets[] for the amount of daylight saving at the transition. If this value is zero, it means
>   that no daylight saving, not the index value zero.
>       The least significant 4-bit field is an index value to offsets[] for total GMT offset at the transition.
>
> If this time zone doesn't observe daylight saving time and has never
>   changed any GMT offsets in the past, this value is null.

Comment: Thanks but, What are "stSavings, useDaylight, transitions and rules" for? @Alexandre Lavoie

Comment: @MaheshVarma now everything is answered!

Answer (score 2):

Check  [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10707238/locale-getdefault-returns-en-always) to understand how Locale.getDefault() actually works.

As for your output for `System.out.println(java.util.TimeZone.getDefault());`

1. DST Savings: The base implementation returns 3600000 (1 hour) for
   time zones that use daylight savings time and 0 for timezones that
   do not
2. Offset: This is the offset of your timezone w.r.t GMT. For India,
   it is 5hr30min which is  19800000 ms
3. UseDaylight: This shows that there is no daylight adjustment for
   this timezone .
4. Transitions: This refers to the daylight saving time transitions
   of a timezone.
5. LastRule: Returns a SimpleTimeZone object representing the last GMT
   offset and DST schedule or null if this time zone doesn't observe
   DST.

Hope this helps.